# Determine number of integral coordinates lying inside or on a quadrilateral?

Tags: algorithm, graphics

Can someone tell me any algorithm by which I can find total number of integral coordinates lying inside or on a quadrilateral. The coordinates of the quadrilateral will be given as input and you have to tell total no. of coordinates lying inside or on a quadrilateral.
For example if the points given are (5,3) (1,1) (3,4) (6,1) then answer should be 14. If you draw the quadrilateral then you will find that only 14 integral coordinates like (3,2),(5,1)..etc lies inside and on the quadrilateral.

Comment: I don't get your question. Can you be more verbose? Is the integration rule living only on th quadrilateral or something else? What rule, what order?

Comment: @user2799037: Added some more info to my question. Kindly recheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your quadrilateral vertices have integer coordinates, then it is possible to use [Pick's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem).

```
A = i + b/2 - 1
```

where A is area, i is the number of interior integer points, and b is the number of integer points at the borders (edges). 
You can find quad area with any method (for example, [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_area#Area_and_centroid)), and find number of border points on every edge as [GCD(dx, dy)](http://nrich.maths.org/535/solution)  (+1 term excluded to avoid counting vertices twice)

Comment: Thanks a lot MBo. I just want to know if there is any method for a polygon (having all vertices at integer coordinates) as well?

Comment: This method works for any polygon with vertices at integer coordinates